# Delete files on OpenVMS 7.2 from live environment?

Tags: linux, livecd, openvms

I am responsible for getting a machine working that is running OpenVMS 7.2-1, but currently it's hard drive is full such that errors are caused during boot when various services try to create log files. My thought to fix this was to delete some unnecessary files so that the log files can be created successfully, but I am missing the installation media, and so I don't have access to the live environment provided for such recovery operations. Is it possible to use a Linux live environment to delete files from an ODS5 partition? The only drivers I've found so far are read-only, and thus won't work to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a mininum boot, and then delete some files to make space.

You'll want to get to SYSBOOT, set startup_P1 to "MIN" and then continue the boot.

Comment: Thanks! After looking at some documentation on SYSBOOT, though, I'm still stuck on how to get to that prompt without installation media. Is that possible?

Comment: Boot commands and sequences are hardware specific - you'll need to check your hardware documentation or tell us what you have and if I think to check back here, and I have time to research it, I'll tell you.